# Why is my alpha texture repeating as a triangle shape?

Tags: texturing, transparency

I've been designing a 3D intro where a logo, split up into 64 squares, comes out of the bottom smoothly. I used an online tool to split up my logo into 64 squares. For example,

[image: top-left corner] is the top left corner piece. I added this as a texture and made a material, but for some unknown reason, it displays like this:

[image: texture]

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. Under the Mapping submenu in the Texture pane, the Coordinates need to be set to Generated. It then appears normally, like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.